# Stability of $a$ implies $\lim _{t\to \infty} x(t)= a$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I have the differential equation $x'=f(x),x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $a$ be a stable point of the differential equation, I want to prove that if $x(t)$ is a solution such that $\forall \delta>0\;\exists t_{\delta}>0$ for which $d(x(t_{\delta}),a)<\delta$ then $\lim_{t\to +\infty}x(t)=a$.

The stability of $a$ allow me to say that given $\epsilon_0$ exists $\delta_0$ such that if $x_0\in B_{\delta_0}(a)$ then $x(t)\in B_{\epsilon_0}(a)$ $\forall t>0$. Using this I have that given $\epsilon$ there's $\delta$ such that if $d(x(t_{\delta}),a)<\delta$ then $d(x(t),a)<\epsilon$, which would be $\lim_{x(t_{\delta})\to a}x(t)=a$.

But how the condition $x(t_{\delta})\to a$ is equivalent to the infinite limit above, which imply I have to show there's a $T$ such that if $t>T$ then $d(x(t),a)<\epsilon$ ?

Or is it enough to put $T=0$? The former condition of stabilioty for $a$ says that with will be $d(x(t),a)<\epsilon$ for every $t>0$, the I have the limit I'm looking for and that's the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have to show that 
$$\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists\, T \text{ such that } t>T \implies d(x(t),a)<\epsilon \tag{1}$$
No, $T=0$ will not work here: it can only work for the constant function $x(t)\equiv 0$. The point you are missing is that when you apply the stated definition of stability, the orbit $x$ will not be   the same $x$ as in (1): time shift is required.

Here is the process:

1. Given $\epsilon>0$, take $\delta>0$ from the definition of stability.
2. Let $t_\delta$ be such that $d(x(t_{\delta}),a)<\delta$
3. Apply the definition of stability to $\tilde x(t)=x(t+t_\delta)$. The function $\tilde x$ also satisfies the autonomous ODE, with initial value $\tilde x_0=x(t_\delta)$.
4. Since $d(\tilde x(t),a)<\epsilon$ for all $t>0$, we have $d(  x(t),a)<\epsilon$ for all $t>t_\delta$
5. Thus, $T=t_\delta$ works in (1).